# javascript DropZone Dynamic Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I looked through several dynamic dropzone example and I don't feel they are very similar... Here is one I looked at very closely:

[Dynamically add dropzone.js div element to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323417/dynamically-add-dropzone-js-div-element-to-the-form)

I don't quite understand his solution, but I have pretty much the exact issue. When I clone and append the div that has the dropzone, the dropzone just doesn't respond... can't even have a popup to select pictures. If have the exact same dropzone multiple times but its pre-loaded, it runs correctly. This shows nothing wrong with my script but dropzone not initialized for the newly added dropzones?

I simplified the code below:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    maxFilesize: 25,
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        this.on("success", function(file, dataURL) {
            //etc...
        });
    }
<div id="cloneme">
<div>Some data - used js to change on clone</div>
<form action="/uploadtoURL" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
        <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Please help! What should I add or adjust to make dropzone reinitialized? I am totally lost.

EDIT:
I just added a dropzone - dynamically, not using clone but very similar. Initial dropzone works, but using an add-on dropzone form doesn't seem to respond or behave like a dropzone at all.

```
$(div).find('.table').after($('<form action="/uploadtoURL" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" style="text-align: center;"><div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message=""><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>'));
```

Comment: I was trying to replicate your problem but cloning it with jQuery works just fine, maybe include the code that clones it in the question to be able to help you

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit this tomorrow when I get a chance!

Comment: @dnetix I added the append dropzone example above. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to be working correctly.