# jQuery File Upload in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-file-upload

I am having issues with jQuery file upload integration onto my project. In my previous post, [javascript DropZone Dynamic Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081827/javascript-dropzone-dynamic-issue?noredirect=1#comment52062920_32081827), I couldn't find a solution so I am looking for alternatives.
I want to be able to use this in a bootstrap modal, but I couldn't get it working. If I just set it outside of modal, it is working fine.
To simplify the code, I pretty much copy and paste from jQuery File Upload website: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html. You can find the code below. Setting the code below inside modal, it won't work. Outside of modal, it'll work fine.

What I tried is setting the z-index of table to 9999, but that didn't do any good. The table is not showing the thumbnail or anything.
Any suggestions?

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Demo Notes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li>The maximum file size for uploads in this demo is <strong>999 KB</strong> (default file size is unlimited).</li>
                <li>Only image files (<strong>JPG, GIF, PNG</strong>) are allowed in this demo (by default there is no file type restriction).</li>
                <li>Uploaded files will be deleted automatically after <strong>5 minutes or less</strong> (demo files are stored in memory).</li>
                <li>You can <strong>drag &amp; drop</strong> files from your desktop on this webpage (see <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support">Browser support</a>).</li>
                <li>Please refer to the <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">project website</a> and <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">documentation</a> for more information.</li>
                <li>Built with the <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> CSS framework and Icons from <a href="http://glyphicons.com/">Glyphicons</a>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you got this resolved, the solution is in this [link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-file-uploader-not-working-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog?reply=true) but it did not quite work for me yet.